# How should I build this code? I receive the following error on flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

ERROR:
Object? data()
package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart

Contains all the data of this document snapshot.

Copied from DocumentSnapshot.

```
The argument type 'Object?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Map<String, dynamic>'
```

- the problem occurs in `element.data ()`

this is my code:

```
Future<void> getAllJobApplications() async {
    if (_uid != null) {
      try {
        _jobApplicationService.getAllJobApplications(_uid!).listen((event) {
          _jobApplications.clear();
          event.docs.forEach((element) {
            _jobApplications
                .add(JobApplication.fromJson(element.data(), element.id));
          });
        });
      } catch (er) {
        print(er);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is showing up because you're trying to assign a value with [a generic type](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/QueryDocumentSnapshot/data.html), `element.data()`, to the parameter in `JobApplication.fromJson()`, with a type of `Map<String, dynamic>`.

You need to specify the type for the `element.data()`.

You can do that by casting `element.data()` to `Map<String, dynamic>` as shown below:

```
element.data() as Map<String, dynamic>
```

and it can be used like this:

```
JobApplication.fromJson(element.data() as Map<String, dynamic>, element.id)
```